# Где объявить PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON

Tags: android, sqlite

Ее необходимо включить перед созданием базы данных в методе onCreate(); перед созданием таблиц? Или же она включается перед обращением к базе данных из клиента?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все PRAGMA нужно объявлять здесь `SQLiteOpenHelper.onOpen(SQLiteDatabase)`
Выглядит это примерно так :

```
class MyDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
@Override
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase myDatabase){       
            myDataBase.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON");
    }
}
```